# set command not working to set the value of a variable on a venv

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I've set up a fixture on pytest which requires a BROWSER environment to be set. However when I set it on the terminal on pycharm on a dummy test (set BROWSER=chrome) Then run pytest. I get the error I raised: `Exception: THE ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE 'BROWSER' MUST BE SET`

Fixture code:

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
import os


@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def init_driver(request):
    pass

    supported_browsers = ['chrome', 'ch' , 'firefox', 'ff']

    browser = os.environ.get('BROWSER')
    if not browser:
        raise Exception("tHE ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE 'BROWSER' MUST BE SET")
    browser = browser.lower()

    if browser not in supported_browsers:
        raise Exception(f" Provided browser '{browser} is not supported"
                        f"supported_browser are : {supported_browsers}")

    if browser in ('chrome', 'ch'):
     driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    elif browser in ('firefox' , 'ff'):
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()


    request.cls.driver= driver
    yield
    driver.quit()
```

dummy test code:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("init_driver")
class Testdummy():

    def test_dumb_func(self):
        print(" i am dumb 1")
        print(" i am dumb 2")
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

Tried the set command and expected it to work

Comment: Are you running `pytest` in the same terminal session as where you are setting the `BROWSER` env var?